# Blooming Problems 4

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> From Athenian gold is where I get most of my name;
>
> Europe is no place if you want to see me tame.
>
> Home of the redwoods for an American introduction;
>
> Short me for endearment toward a parent, for you have suction.

Can you name this flower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> A CHRYSANTHEMUM?

From Athenian gold is where I get most of my name;

> CHRYSOS is the Greek word for Gold. (The other half comes from the Greek word *anthemon*, meaning flower.)

Europe is no place if you want to see me tame.

> They were first native to China and Japan.

Home of the redwoods for an American introduction;

> The Enomoto Brothers of Redwood City, California were the first to cultivate them in the US.

Short me for endearment toward a parent, for you have suction.

> This sounds like MUM.

Comment: Good job, you're correct

Comment: El-Guest, you're always beating me to the punch! Great answer!

Comment: Thanks, @PerpetualJ! Must have been a close race! :D

Comment: *Typing my answer* "1 new answer has been posted." Hrm, I wonder? :)

Comment: Are you working my new riddle by chance? Usually you or Joe typically comment by now. Must be proving quite challenging? :D